# How to build a frontend for my youtube video downloader program?

Tags: python, reactjs

I want to build a basic frontend for the below program, so that when users enter the app they will get the same output as in a python interpreter.
here is the python code

```
from pytube import YouTube

def Download(link):
  youtubeObject = YouTube(link)
  youtubeObject = youtubeObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
  try:
      youtubeObject.download()
  except:
    print("There has been an error in downloading your youtube video")
  print("This download has completed! Yahooooo!")

link = input("Put your youtube link here!! URL: ")
Download(link)
```

I am expecting to build a small app where users can enter their video link and download the video. I just want to learn how to integrate it with a good looking user interface.

Comment: You need to have webserver to host the html page, build the webpage.... And still another things to do.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. A web browser cannot interpret python, so your python code will live on an another computer.
2. That another computer is a server, and to communicate with the server, you'll need an API route. e.g `(/process)`
3. The frontend will hit the API with the link as a parameter. (let's say) `(/process?link=<youtube-link>)`
4. The logic for handling that API will be written on the server. You can choose any language for that. Since you're familiar with Python already, use Flask or Fast API.
5. Once you host your server code you're ready for communicating with the front-end with simple Fetch API.

### References:

1. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/
2. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Thanks, will  try  to build using flask framework.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just completed a similar project: Here is the working code for your reference linking the frontend and backend together. Cheers :)

```
from tkinter import *
import pytube
from pytube import *

video = None

def window():
  global root
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry('500x300')
  root.resizable(0,0)
  root.title("YouTube Downloader")

  # YouTube label creation
  ytd = Label(root, text="YouTube Videos download for free", font=("TimesNewRoman", 20, "bold italic"))
  ytd.pack()

  # Link entry field
  link = StringVar()
  link_label = Label(root, text="Paste Link Here:", font="arial 20 bold")
  link_label.place(x=160, y=60)
  link_entry = Entry(root, width=70, textvariable=link)
  link_entry.place(x=32, y=90)

  # Download button
  download_button = Button(root, text="DOWNLOAD", font="arial 15 bold", bg="Blue", padx=2, command=lambda: Downloader(link.get()))
  download_button.place(x=180, y=150)

  # Downloaded label
  downloaded_label = Label(root, text="DOWNLOADED", font="arial 15")

def Downloader(link):
  youtubeObject = YouTube(link)
  youtubeObject = youtubeObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
  try:
      youtubeObject.download()
      print("This download was completed successfully!. Youtube thief!")
  except:
    
    print("There was an error downloading the youtube video, Please try again!")

if video is not None:
    video.Downloader()
    downloaded_label.pack()

window()
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__window__":
  main()
```